# MVC model not binding on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. When the form in the view is posted the model properties turn out to be null.

### Model

```
public class RegistrationModel
{
    public RegistrationModel()
    {
        Registration = new REGISTRATION();
        AddPayment = true;
    }
    public REGISTRATION Registration { get; set; }
    public bool AddPayment { get; set; }
}
```

### View

```
@model Client.Models.RegistrationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors: false)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("SECTION_ID", null, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("STUDENT_ID", null, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("STATUS_ID", null, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AddPayment)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

### Controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //code to populate view dropdowns
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(RegistrationModel model)
    {
        WriteFileLog(_logPath, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
    }
```

In the controller's Create action that handles the post model properties are null.

Registration Class (autogenerated by EF from database):

```
public partial class REGISTRATION
{
    public REGISTRATION()
    {
        this.REGISTRATION_AUDIT = new HashSet<REGISTRATION_AUDIT>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SECTION_ID { get; set; }
    public int STUDENT_ID { get; set; }
    public int STATUS_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<REGISTRATION_AUDIT> REGISTRATION_AUDIT { get; set; }
    public virtual SECTION SECTION { get; set; }
    public virtual V_REGISTRATION_STATUS V_REGISTRATION_STATUS { get; set; }
    public virtual PERSON PERSON { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: show your `REGISTRATION` class.

Comment: The code you have show will work fine (the parameter `model` will not be `null`). If its not working, then its due to something you have not shown us.

Comment: @DanielA.White registration class added

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is what newtonsoft's serializer says about the posted model: `{"Registration":null,"AddPayment":false}`

Comment: Debug your code and check the actual `model` parameter - it will not be `null` based on the code you have shown. Although most of the values of your properties will be their defaults because your dropdownlists do not bind to any model properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the strongly-typed helpers, like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Registration.SECTION_ID, null, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Otherwise, you need to adjust the names you're using to

```
@Html.DropDownList("Registration.SECTION_ID", null, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

You can probably simplify what you're doing by duplicating the Registration class's members into your view model, replacing the Registration property.

As @StephenMuecke points out, you're missing a few parts from your model/markup. The template for the [DropDownList helper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx) you're using is

```
DropDownListFor(
    [model property to bind], 
    [collection of possible values to bind], 
    [option label], 
    [HTML attributes])
```

Passing null for that second parameter means you have no values to populate the generated `<select>` element with, and should normally generate an exception.

I'm not a fan of using ViewBag to pass collections into the view, so I'd recommend something like

```
public class RegistrationModel
{
    public RegistrationModel()
    {
        Registration = new REGISTRATION();
        AddPayment = true;
    }
    public REGISTRATION Registration { get; set; }
    public bool AddPayment { get; set; }

    public SelectList Sections { get; set; }

    public SelectList Students { get; set; }

    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

and then adjust the markup accordingly:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Registration.SECTION_ID, Model.Sections, string.Empty, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: The second parameter would need to refer to a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property (e.g. `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SECTION_ID` based on OP's code

Comment: @StephenMuecke True, I would assume if this was working at all before that there are bits left out of the question. I suppose to be a more complete answer I should point that out and suggest an implementation, no?

Comment: Your answer (assuming you correct the 2nd parameter so it does not throw an exception) only explains why the value of `SECTION_ID` of `Registration` would be `0` in the POST method, not why `model` is `null` as OP is claiming, so more info is required from OP.

Comment: @TiesonT. the strongly typed dropdown solved the issue. +1 for great explanation!

Comment: @greatbear302, So in fact, you model was **not** null (just the properties of your model were not binding and the`int` values were `0`) - you should reword you question.